# iPhone - Poor Performance of a UITableView with a UIScrollView of UIImageViews in each cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UIScrollView`.  The UIScrollView contains a different number of `UIImageViews` for each row.  Some rows have 5 images in the scroll view, some rows have 15 images in the scroll view.  Since the number of `UIImageViews` in each row is different, I'm stuck allocating new `UIImageViews` when each row is drawn!  This is obviously having a negative impact on scroll performance of my `UITableView`.  How can I resolve this to improve `UITableView` scrolling?

Additionally, using Instruments' Time Profiler, I've noticed that the method call `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier]` is abnormally slow.  Does that help point to the problem?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"HuddleTableCell";

HuddleListItemTableViewCell *cellToReturn = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cellToReturn == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HuddleListItemTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cellToReturn = cell;

    UILabel *badgeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    badgeLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    badgeLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    badgeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    badgeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    badgeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cellToReturn.attendee4Image addSubview:badgeLabel];
    cellToReturn.othersOverlayLabel = badgeLabel;
    [badgeLabel release];
    cellToReturn.heartHolderView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

    cellToReturn.heartHolderView.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.29 green:.39 blue:.57 alpha:1.0] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.19 green:.22 blue:.36 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.102 green:.122 blue:.17 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];
    cellToReturn.heartHolderView.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColorFromRGB(0x4A59A8) CGColor], nil];
    cellToReturn.heartHolderView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

    UIView *polaroidView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 37, 39)];
    polaroidView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    polaroidView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
    polaroidView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
    polaroidView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);
    polaroidView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 29, 29)];
    [polaroidView addSubview:img];
    [cellToReturn.organizerImage addSubview:polaroidView];
    cellToReturn.polaroidView = polaroidView;
    cellToReturn.polaroidImageView = img;
    [img release];
    [polaroidView release];

    cellToReturn.gradientView.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.96 green:.96 blue:.96 alpha:1.0] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:.85 green:.85 blue:.85 alpha:1.0] CGColor], nil];

    cellToReturn.votingTimerLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x616163);
    cellToReturn.eventDateLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x616163);
    cellToReturn.eventNameLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x616163);
    cellToReturn.numInviteesLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x616163);
    cellToReturn.numVotesLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x616163);

    self.cell = nil;
}

NSString *organizerFbId = [[self.huddleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"userId"];
[cellToReturn.polaroidImageView setImageWithURL:[self.organizerImageUrls objectForKey:organizerFbId] placeholderImage:self.placeholderImage];

[[cellToReturn.imageScrollViewHolder subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
if ([self.avatarScrollViews objectForKey:[[self.huddleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"id"]]) {
    [cellToReturn.imageScrollViewHolder addSubview:[self.avatarScrollViews objectForKey:[[self.huddleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"id"]]];
} else {
    UIScrollView *tempImageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 46)];
    tempImageScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    NSArray *fbUids = [[self.huddleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"facebookInvitees"];
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i < [fbUids count];i++) {
        UIView *polaroidView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i * 45) + (3 * i), 0, 37, 39)] autorelease];
        polaroidView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        polaroidView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
        polaroidView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
        polaroidView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);

        polaroidView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        UIImageView *img = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 29, 29)] autorelease];
        [img setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", [fbUids objectAtIndex:i]]] placeholderImage:self.placeholderImage];
        [polaroidView addSubview:img];
        [tempImageScrollView addSubview:polaroidView];
    }
    [tempImageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((i*45) + (3 * i), 46)];
    [self.avatarScrollViews setObject:tempImageScrollView forKey:[[self.huddleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"id"]];
    [cellToReturn.imageScrollViewHolder addSubview:tempImageScrollView];
    [tempImageScrollView release];
}

return cellToReturn;
}
```

Comment: I think it's more of a design issue here. Mobile devices aren't that powerful to handle so many scroll views. Plus, you won't be needing to scroll so many views at one time. Consider revise your design, and only make scroll views when it's necessary to scroll?

Comment: Good point, although I'm just trying to implement the design being provided to me.  Isn't there something I can do?

Comment: Have a discussion with your designer about how to improve its efficiency.  For example, perhaps you could show a preview in each cell, and only show the full set of images when the user selects a row.

Comment: @obuseme, the bottom line is you can have only one scroll view at a time. Usually if ``UITableView`` is used as primary interface, I would navigate to a new controller to display scrolling info upon cell selection. If you do need to somehow put lots of stuff into one cell, consider putting some brief info by default, such as one label or one image. When it's selected, reconstruct the view (without an additional scroll view of course), and call ``tableView beginUpdates`` and ``tableView endUpdates`` to animate cell resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even there was a fixed number of images in each cell's scroller, you'd be stuck allocating them as the cells are dequeued and reused.  The way to get speed is to take up some more space, by keeping the cells' subviews in an array outside of the table.

Create another array that has the same count as your huddleList array.  Fill that array with UIScrollViews containing the imageViews.  All that code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method can move to the initialization method for the new array and get replaced by a few simple lines:

```
// dequeue or build a cell

// tag the scroll views so you can find them
UIScrollView *oldScrollView = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:kCELL_SCROLL_VIEW];

// this might be a reused cell, so remove the scroll view if it has one
if (oldScrollView) [oldScrollView removeFromSuperview];

// now add the one that you setup for this cell
// your init code that used to be in this method sets up the frame, the tag, etc
UIScrollView *currentScrollView = [self.cachedScrollViews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell addSubview:currentScrollView];

// that's it
```

Don't forget to release the cachedScrollViews on memory warning

Comment: Isn't this what I'm already doing with the array "avatarScrollViews" ?

Comment: Could be (I answered more about the common problem than the code).  Look for anything you alloc in that method.  Besides the cell itself, each of those is an opportunity to speed up.

Comment: Where would you propose I move the alloc'ing of the scrollviews?  Keeping memory in mind, I wouldn't want to create a scroll view for every possible row before the table is drawn.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm suggesting.  (Do it before the table will be seen, e.g. viewWillAppear).  Are we talking about 10s or even low hundreds of rows?  I don't see an alternative if you want the list to scroll smoothly.  (Though I agree with the other commenters that your customer should probably rethink the requirement).